# Error: "More than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

```
Select Max(valid_to) from table1  GROUP BY ( Select a FROM table2 WHERE ...);
```

I get error msg:

> more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

because second query return more than one value.

How to fix it?

Comment: If you want subquery to return one row, then you should use an aggregate function in subquery. For example Select Max(a) should do the trick. But this may not result in what you expect. You should define what you want to do first.

Comment: You must describe what you are trying to achieve before anybody can help. What you show so far, doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your query is that it's wrong on principal. Even if you limit the number of rows returned by the subquery, it's still nonsense.

```
GROUP BY (SELECT anycolumn FROM anytable LIMIT 1)
```

Is effectively the same as:

```
GROUP BY some_constant_value_from_column_anytable_anycolumn
```

which doesn't do *anything*.

Comment: it does something if `a` specifies the column order number to group

Comment: @MiguelRoxo: One might hope that works, except that it **doesn't**. Ordinal numbers (positional references) to reference output columns (like `GROUP BY 1`) cannot be paremeterized. `1` is not a *value* here. Try it .. To achieve something like that you would have to build your query string dynamically - and be wary of SQL injection.